# Additive Secret Sharing of Floating point numbers

Tags: secret-sharing

Consider a floating point number $f$ in IEEE 754 format with sign, exponent and significand values as $f.s$, $f.e$, and $f.sig$. Given this floating point number $f$, I want to compute the shares of $f$, denoted as $f1$ and $f2$, such that $f=f_1{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}f_2$, where ${\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}$ denotes the usual floating point addition in IEEE-754 format. This [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/280203/1-s2.0-S1877050913X00079/1-s2.0-S1877050913008843/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHgaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIE%2BNSpMcgrduAaquJ7i8maScbEn%2FrI5gDQaEwTLEn7guAiAVqDxD6u%2FB%2F8xQ0HGpR2FybzjGQCGL8XIxdZg8kU%2Flfyq7BQjR%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMsJjzXN2v78ahoEWYKo8F9xHhS6G5eHUoVxw8RvH0VeQGcstqFuZKCVmF8344PkjBsxhLUP5b9kOrMup72ebH7Uuc9VWmY0s48d23TxlEDFy237nSMuelOleE2Qf0jiHclPKZKTjXYNTbSR0gb6q4j3xGVB12lhSH%2BtJlukbV2TNfEMZwxFn%2BbeJHlPMiemmNjwGiBssij4sLjzaRVaurJ6yzoloPIjt9SgtB5gMDfmsZ54rL3Q0HjIWXqFUdCQVk8TAXGXsokApOABjSRap6vNP1e%2FguS%2Fn9i%2FoejUBJu2lBFuoKtBGNedp5BmJHiQ2lH8tGzN0MXvXoQonhigJnBrvk6thCRr%2BN5D5XxSxJADPNTRedO4bof%2F70AzDjn1ndrgkcE9r2Dm9ezCAisQQeNrotvw6QaVquYeKgmo8hJhMirWGIlL2hb5vCpdMXAhf%2FpUIqL2XGZ%2Bw5E2QnIoRA8SVKIBtyxx6Q1chqKmJaoOxtPEm7jpqvf1wKNyO2iKdS7YEdNzpUzH3NVV%2Fp81Dq%2Bq1qOnDrtqcha8HHZo511ZxEm3NDXChFwv9JA%2Fz3%2FZ%2F6B%2F9zmSQXJnFrf02Hrvw3CGlijnBiDyXA%2BFlc%2F70xlr0AMxV3xzkRgKk%2FMReRrOTdcAhHh5tgThcN%2FpzTqWRuIr0cSOLAUTeOVbBPMXYlbT44gjWTwEd%2BaK30YKFU1Au6pCXj9yfLkSpd2o0TWIlU3KzNIkRjFS66RCsdGvrAW9DtC4bgsln%2FDSZqKcfYl69v6i8s39fl3dmoMuyM90bJ2SUJDTfEnsFDW%2F256K%2BknQIwR9tYZtQwEk2aTczw3VD7nEbgFWlOSYXPBCTYYaRx8u7SiPO4rvt8t8Zk%2B58o0aTq73DSWHAnY6uUbHML4DDw3ZurBjqyATsIjWNuuGOQ%2FSlTS8SpesKqFBCGcF6XoCBUk4jxisXZp4lUAFcmUe4DfBDW3fvsYUB81tA7nLEhlusbJjiS0ei%2FC7AM8L2FjdD4sB8GxE7%2FF0abXjZl3erqS9z20nqbjxLZWefW2JbvwK6JO87leKYxVGzqHsCBMXjXHq6Zb5Q4mKisYZ9w8XxTQanNQRWpevO58RJrkWKvLN%2FodeMUR%2FV5mdw11w9BfdWgx3JWXZFK14k%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231129T082216Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYXI5WHTXB%2F20231129%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=3651ae75ff2ff89b65062a36dee5c9d9256b903f96f98e2aa11279ba4fc4d4a9&hash=17dd30787ebaea7114ab6038a224ef69665fdf141f3d2e41b4b8caa4e77c35a7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1877050913008843&tid=spdf-9798bdb3-7e19-4eaa-9f96-5d0527bb39e9&sid=fe7126e247836146541b3f86e373085d03b3gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1b055f50015656565309&rr=82d9711f58b217d7&cc=ae) states that due to complexity of  operations such as alignment and normalization, component wise secret sharing of floating point numbers are performed, where the sign, exponent and significand values are additively shared over different rings. However, I didn't find any additive secret-sharing scheme over floating point numbers that holds $f_1{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}f_2$. Because of this, I tried to achieve such secret sharing as follows:

1. Obtain $f1.s$, $f1.e$, and $f1.sig$ over rings $Z_s$, $Z_e$, and $Z_{sig}$ respectively to denote the secret shared FP value $f1$.
2. I perform a floating point subtraction operation over these different rings (denoted as ${\underset{\mathsf{FP}}-}$) to obtain $f2.s$, $f2.e$, and $f2.sig$, such that $f2 =f{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}-}f_1$. All the operations of ${\underset{\mathsf{FP}}-}$ are performed under the rings  $Z_s$, $Z_e$, and $Z_{sig}$ over the respective sign, exponent, and significand values.

As a result of these steps, I obtain $<f1.s, f1.e, f1.sig>$ and $<f2.s, f2.e, f2.sig>$ which represents the values $f1$ and $f2$. I use these triplets to continue performing various FP operations over the ring to obtain my desired functionality. However, I observed one concern in this secret-sharing scheme. If either of $f1.s$ or $f2.s$ is $1$, then it indicates that the corresponding value of $f1$ or $f2$ is negative. Suppose $f1.s = 1$, indicating value $f1$ is negative. This implies that the value $f2 > f$ which leaks some information about the secret $f$.

Is this information leakage acceptable during this secret-sharing scheme or is there any other way to perform this kind of secret sharing such that $f=f_1{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}f_2$ holds?
Is there any paper that uses this kind of additive secret-sharing scheme over FP numbers?

Comment: Are you secret sharing the sign, exponent, significand separately?  If you have independent secret shares of each one, I don't understand how you can perform floating point arithmetic between these shares since floating point operations are non-linear?

Comment: We can perform operations on the sign, exponent and significand values between f1 and f, using usual FP arithmetic, such as difference handlings of exponent and significand, normalization, and rounding. The non-linearity comes from the precision limitations inherent in representing real numbers with finite precision. This error will not be challenging while obtaining the resulting exponent. However, while computing the significand and normalization step, we use variable bit lengths to maintain the precision. We use the ideas of SoftFloat and SecFloat to achieve that.

Comment: Usually, FP sharing is performed by additively sharing each of the sign, exponent, and mantissa values over different rings or fields like the linked paper, or the most recent [SecFloat](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/322.pdf) paper, etc. Thus, the resulting shares do not ensure $f=f_1{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}f_2$. I wanted to know if a secret sharing over FP is possible where $f=f_1{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}f_2$ holds. If this sharing is possible then various FP computations in MPC can be performed with very high accuracy. I tried to come up with an approach that seems theoretically incorrect.

Comment: You can look into the most recent paper [SecFloat](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/322.pdf) for better clarity on how the computations on the individual secret shares of sign, exponent, and mantissa are done. For example, secret sharing of exponents is performed over ring $2^{10}$. They have also provided their source code [here](https://github.com/mpc-msri/EzPC/tree/master/SCI).

Comment: In the question, are the sign, exponent and significand/mantissa of $f_1$ and $f_2$: (A) known to one participant for the fields of $f_1$, the other participant for the fields of $f_2$, as assumed in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/108855/555); or (B) each split into two uniformly random shares, one for each participant, as in the first linked article if I read it correctly?

Comment: Say, if there are two parties $P1$ and $P2$, the sign, exponent, and significand/mantissa of the share $f1$ is only known to party $P1$ and the sign, exponent and significand/mantissa of $f2$ is only known to $P2$.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose $f1.s = 1$, indicating value $f1$ is negative. This implies that the value $f1 > f$ which leaks some information about the secret $f$.

Actually, no it doesn't imply that (unless you always have $f1.s = f2.s$ - I didn't see that in your overview).  Whether $f$ is larger or smaller than $f1$ depends on the sign of $f2$, and we assume that an attacker doesn't learn information about $f1$ and $f2$ simultaneously.

On the other hand, if the recombination step is "IEEE floating point addition", some information leakage is inevitable.  To take a simple example, if $f1 = 2^{80}$, then the attacker who has $f1$ can know that $f \ne 1$ (or any small positive value) - that's because there's no possible floating point representation $f2$ with $2^{80} + f2 = 1$.

Whether this amount of leakage (and similar, less obvious leakages) is acceptable would depend on the application and the data being protected.

Comment: I'm at a loss about what's known by who. You wrote "we assume that an attacker doesn't learn information about $f_1$ and $f_2$ simultaneously". But my understanding (from the linked 2013 article, and to a degree from the SecFloat paper) was that each party knows a randomized share of both $f_1$ and $f_2$, revealing nothing, and aims to compute a randomized share of $f=f_1{\underset{\mathsf{FP}}+}f_2$ (or some other operator), so that ultimately recombining the shares of $f$ yields the correct result. I'm even more puzzled about what exchanges occur during that computation.

Comment: @fgrieu: the terminology I was using is that $f1, f2$ are the two shares of one secret $f$.  I reviewed the question, and it appeared to me that was the intended usage by Sumana

Comment: Thanks @poncho for your answer. Sorry, I miswrote the question. Actually, if $f1$ is negative, it implies that $f2>f$ for all scenarios as $f2 = f - f1$. This is an information leakage regarding f, right? Is this acceptable?

Also, I get your point on the "recombination step" which may leak some information. However, in my application that is acceptable.

Comment: @SumanaBagchi: unless the adversary has some information about $f2$, this is not information leakage.  All he knows is "the unknown value I want to know is less than some other value I also do not know" - this doesn't tell the adversary anything.  What I would also be worried about is the distribution of $f1, f2$ for a particular $f$ values - unless that is done carefully, the resulting distribution of (say) $f1$ may give the adversary some clue about $f$

Comment: @poncho: I got your point about the distributions of $f1$ and $f2$ given the example you have given in your answer. What if the secret $f$ is distributed into three shares $f1$, $f2$, and $f3$ in an honest majority setting? In such a scenario any information regarding the individual share will not be possible to derive without any collusion.